# How do I access the individual fetchedobjects from fetchedresultscontroller?

Tags: ios

In my core data, there are 2 entities namely Order and OrderItems

Each order contains various OrderItems.

In my ExportReportViewController, I have written code to retrieve the orders based on two given dates and I want to write them to a csv file and email it out to whoever that needs the information.

There is however one issue, I am not able to access the individual objects that I have retrieved using fetchedresultscontroller which leads to me not being able to retrieve the orderitems that is tied to each order.

My code for retrieving the objects are

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Sale"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"createdAt >= %@ && createdAt < %@", fromDate, toDate];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

[self.fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];

NSError *error = nil;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

Using this line of code, I am able to retrieve all the OrderID of the orders that I have retrieved,

```
NSArray *orderIDArray = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] valueForKey:@"orderID"];
```

In my other controller that is a tableview, I am able to access the individual objects using just this line of code:

```
NSManagedObject *order = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Following by this line which lets me retrieve the array of orderitems that is tied to each order

```
NSArray *orderItems = [[order mutableSetValueForKey:@"orderitems"]allObjects];
```

However as this is just a viewcontroller, I am not able to do that as there is no indexpath.

Anyone knows how am I able to access the individual objects that is retrieved from the fetchedresultscontroller?

Comment: Just iterate through [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects].

Comment: just for loop through the size of the fetchedobjects?

Comment: Yes.  fetchedObjects is an array of all of the objects from the FRC.